# Getting all rows after timestamp cutoff in MySQL

Tags: mysql, date, timestamp, unix-timestamp, datediff

I'm trying to fetch all rows from a table with a UNIX timestamp in the past 30 days.

```
SELECT count(member_id), DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(`join_date`)) as date 
FROM members 
WHERE join_date > (join_date-'2592000')
GROUP BY DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(`join_date`)) 
ORDER BY join_date DESC
```

There's more going on there, obviously, as it groups them by day and converts them to a mysql time, but the important thing is the where clause that's not working.. The rest of it is good.

I'm not getting any errors, but the query isn't cutting off as expected.

[image: Query Result]

EDIT: Got it.

```
SELECT count(member_id), DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(`join_date`)) as date 
FROM exp_members 
WHERE DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), FROM_UNIXTIME(join_date)) < 30
GROUP BY DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(`join_date`)) 
ORDER BY join_date DESC
```

Comment: Is join_date an integer?

Comment: What program are you using there to view the DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This: `WHERE join_date > (join_date-'2592000')` is almost certainly your issue.

You probably want to compare join_date to `CURDATE` (rather than itself-x) using `DATEDIFF` that way you can use whole day increments instead of seconds as 259200 which is better most human-readable-wise.

Comment: Thanks Michael. That's exactly what I ended up doing. Much appreciated.